# Best practice for using react-native modals

Tags: react-native, react-modal

My react-native app has several situations where different models can be presented. I am wondering what's the best way to accomplish this. In general, I see two different approaches:

**a)**
On the root view, I always have the `Modal` component mounted and simply switch the content, like this...

```
<View>
    {...}
    <Modal visible={this.props.modal}>
         {this.props.modal === 1 && <ModalContent1 />}
         {this.props.modal === 2 && <ModalContent2 />}
         {this.props.modal === 3 && <ModalContent3 />}
    </Modal>
</View>
```

**b)** Every modal brings its own `Modal` component and is mounted somewhere in the tree, near the place it is triggered from.

Which way would you prefer and why?

A question that applies to both approaches is if the `Modal`-component should always be mounted and only triggered using the `visible` prop. If that's the way to go, I assume approach b) needs more memory, because multiple instances of the `Modal` component are created.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the **Stack Navigator from [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org)** to implement modals within my application. My modals include a "create post modal", "no internet connection modal" among others.

This allows me to access these modals from anywhere in my application and can persist/block other actions directly. To learn more about how to use React Navigation, you can read up on these two links:

1. To understand the [StackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/), it has a section specifically for **transparent background modals**
2. [To learn](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/) more about implementing modals in React Navigation in general.